# install nupkg programmatically with envDTE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget, envdte

I'm creating a scaffolding tool and want to install a nuget package in a certain project from an EnvDTE extension. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use the method described in [Invoking NuGet Services from inside Visual Studio](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/invoking-nuget-services-from-inside-visual-studio).

In particular, look at the methods on the [IVsPackageInstaller](https://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/VisualStudio/Extensibility/IVsPackageInstaller.cs) service.